# How can you replicate a font with images?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to replace text with images (each character would have its own image), with the ability to update the text on the page and the corresponding images.

For example, I want to be able to output: "SCORE: 1,034" with images, and be able to update the score as the user progresses. As the score gets higher and higher, there would need to be more commas, there would be extra columns of digits, etc. 0 -> 103 -> 1,034 -> 102,304 etc.

I am thinking I would probably have have a single image for "SCORE", and then an image for each number and a comma, but I'm having trouble writing a function that replaces each character with it's corresponding image.

Is there a simple way to do this with JavaScript/jQuery and/or CSS?

Thank you!

Comment: why is that you want an image instead of numbers ?

Comment: I want to use the images so I can use a special font, so the score stands out in a way that normal text cannot.

Comment: Have you considered using an embedded web font instead?

Comment: You can use Cufon JavaScript, it replaces text with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to have an array to hold the url for each digit image url:

```
var digitImages = [
    'http://example.com/0.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/2.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/3.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/4.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/5.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/6.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/7.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/8.jpg', 
    'http://example.com/9.jpg'
];
```

then a simple routing that looks up each digit inside the `digitImages`.

```
var imgs = [];
var text = 130.toString();

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
{
   var index = parseInt(text[i], 0);
   imgs.push(new Image(digitImages[index]));
}
```

now the content of `imgs` array should be all the image elements for number `130` which can be appended to a div or other container elements.

Comment: This is great! I'll use jQuery to append the images to a div. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have a function that takes the number and adds the commas and then you can replace the characters with images.

Sample function

```
function C(a,b){return(a+"").replace(/\d+/,function(a){return a.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,"$&"+(b||','))})}

C(1001)//returns 1,001
```